# Integral with scalar product and norm

Tags: integration

I need to show that for $f\colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ continuous that the following holds for a fixed $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$:

$$\int_{S^n} f(\langle x, y \rangle) d\mu(y) = \int_{S^n} f(\|x\|_2 y_{n+1}) d\mu(y)$$

where $S^{n} = \{y \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}: \|x\|_2 = 1 \}$ and $\langle x, y \rangle$ denotes euclidean scalar product and $\mu$ being a surface measure.

I am unable to find any clever approaches so far. I guess that I should find an orthogonal map because orthongal maps are invariant in $\| \cdot \|_2$ ($\| T(x) \|_2 = \| x \|_2)$ which explains why I need to integrate over $S^{n}$ on both sides. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is "a" surface measure? Do you mean *the* standard way of measuring areas, or just any regular measure on $S^n$?

Comment: $S^{n}$ is a n-dimensional manifold in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, so it is a transformation to $$\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and taking the Lebesgue-measure there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mu$ is rotation invariant then the LHS does not change if we rotate $x$ until it lies on the positive half of the $X_{n+1}$ axis. But then for all $y\in \mathbb R^{n+1},$ $\langle x,y\rangle=x_{n+1}y_{n+1}=|x_{n+1}|y_{n+1}=\|x\|y_{n+1}.$